# Create Java Entity for the expected JSON format

Tags: java

I have JSON in the following format:

```json
"ContactPhone": {
    "item": [
        {
            "id": "3080075",
            "phoneNum": "2222222222",
            "$original": {
                "phoneNum": "2222222222"
            }
        },
        {
            "phoneNum": "7878787878"
        }
    ],
    "$original": {
        "item": [
            {
                "id": "3080075"
            },
            null
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to create an entity something below

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class ContactPhone {
  @JsonProperty("item")
  public List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

  @Data
  public static final class Item {
    @JsonProperty("phoneNum")
    public String phoneNum;
  }

  @Data
  public final class $Original {
    @JsonProperty("item")
    public List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Data
    public static final class Item {
      @JsonProperty("id")
      public String id
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable to set the items for the inner $original class, how to achieve that? thanks in advance

Comment: How are you attempting to set those items? Please include a [mre] that shows your problem.

Comment: Your curly braces are incorrect.